# printing the smarty file content

Tags: include, smarty, preview

i am including template like this:

```
<div id="comments" >
      {include file='comm/comm_all.tpl'}
</div>
```

and i would like to echo the comm_all.tpl contents  to the html.
somthing like that:

```
<div id="comments" >
      {include file='comm/comm_all.tpl'}
</div>
<div id="code_preview" >
      the code previw is:
      {include_function file='comm/comm_all.tpl'}
</div>
```

the include function is what i looking for, and it

should take the file content and print "as it is"
for example:

```
<div id="comments" >
      1. bla bla the show
      2. it`s an array as you guess.
</div>
<div id="code_preview" >
      the code previw is:
      {foreach $array as $i => $v}
           $i. {$v.content}
      {/foreach}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is not within Smarty, but could be done with a plugin function in PHP.

```
<?php

    function include_function($params, $smarty){

        $filename = "{$smarty->template_dir}/{$params['file']}";

        if(file_exists($filename)){
            readfile($filename);
        }

    }

?>
```

---

```
<div id="comments" >
      {include file='comm/comm_all.tpl'}
</div>
<div id="code_preview" >
      the code previw is:
      {include_function file='comm/comm_all.tpl'}
</div>
```

Comment: what i want is within smarty, your output shows the the file content only. in my example there is file including with smarty manipulation and another file include without smarty manipulation.
and all what i discribe above generte inside smarty tpl`s,
yours is inside php file.